# How to get XML from an XCC ResultSequence?

Tags: marklogic

I have this Java code:

```
Request r2 = session.NewAdhocQuery("xdmp:document-properties('" + items + "')");
ResultSequence rs2 = session.SubmitRequest(r2);
```

Now how can I get rs2 in the form of XML?

Answer (score 0):

At https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/ResultSequence.html there's a note on the `toString` method: "Use the XdmSequence.asString() or XdmSequence.asStrings() methods to obtain String representations of the item values." If a ResultSequence contains XML items, its string representation will be XML. So:

```
rs2.asStrings()
```

By the way, using string concatenation to build an ad-hoc query is a serious security flaw because it allows injection attacks. Bind `items` to a variable. There are example at https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/index.html under "Passing Variables With Queries".

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following for getting an xml as string

```
String text = "";
while (resultSequence.hasNext()) {
  XdmValue value = resultSequence.next();
  text = value.asString(); 
}
```